# I have a problem with display link

Tags: java, struts2

the link is not forwording to 1.jsp
this code is not working properly

```
<display:column property="in" sortable="true" href="1.jsp" paramid="1.jsp"/>
```

thanx

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on this link will not go to 1.html but to 1.jsp as you have defined href="1.jsp".

You have defined paramid="1.html" but paramId takes the name of parameter which you want to send to the href url

i.e. if you want 1.jsp?paramName=paramValue then you will define paramId="paramName"

Read the display:column documentation again to understand it better.

Comment: thanx bhusan sir for help me, my problem is solved , in my code there is little mistak , i was seen and resolved it